# What is the best approach for filtering rows and counting unique dates in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a shared activity log of bike rides in Google Sheets that looks like:

| [A] Date | [B] Name | [C] Miles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LTSZxT4bZVHmFONkaCpkV-4AwlKeQZnq0JFx3xSBqns/edit?usp=sharing) Nov 2, 2022 | Joe | 2.1 |
| [2] Nov 2, 2022 | Ray | 1.5 |
| [3] Nov 3, 2022 | Ray | 3.1 |
| [4] Nov 4, 2022 | Joe | 2.9 |
| [5] Nov 4, 2022 | Joe | 2.2 |

This will run the whole month. On another sheet I'd like to show the participants, their active days in the week and the total distance they rode.

Leaderboard for Nov 1 - 5
| [A] Name | [B] Active Days | [C] Distance |
| --- | ----------- | -------- |
| [1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LTSZxT4bZVHmFONkaCpkV-4AwlKeQZnq0JFx3xSBqns/edit?usp=sharing) Joe | =COUNTIFS(...) | =SUMIFS(...) |
| [2] Ray | =COUNTIFS(...) | =SUMIFS(...) |

I created COUNTIFS and SUMIFS like the following:

Cell B2 for Joe `=COUNTIFS(B:B,A1,A:A,">="&DATE(2022,11,1),A:A,"<="&DATE(2022,11,5))`

Cell C2 for Joe `=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,A1,A:A,">="&DATE(2022,11,1),A:A,"<="&DATE(2022,11,5))`

This worked well until I had the situation where someone did two activities in a day, as happens with Joe on Nov 4 (rows 4 and 5). The total miles is correct but I need to have the COUNTIFS take into account *unique* dates. My formula would report 3 when the answer should be 2.

A live Google Sheet [recreating the above is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LTSZxT4bZVHmFONkaCpkV-4AwlKeQZnq0JFx3xSBqns/edit?usp=sharing).

I've played with:

- FILTER: `=FILTER(A:C, B:B = "Joe", A:A >=DATE(2022,11,1), A:A <= DATE(2022,11,5))`
- DCOUNTA: `=DCOUNTA(A:C,"Date",{{"Name";"Joe"},{"Date";">=Nov 1, 2022"},{"Date";"<=Nov 5, 2022"}})`
- QUERY: `=COUNT(UNIQUE(QUERY(Log!A:C, "select A where B = 'Joe' and A >=date'2022-11-1' and A <=date'2022-11-05'")))`

The QUERY above seems to work feels a little wonky. I'm wondering if there are suggestions at better ways to go about this?

Comment: Try to solve your problem with another tool: [**Insert - Pivot Table**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a formula like this to stablish the count of unique days for each:

> =counta(unique(FILTER(Log!A:A, Log!B:B = "Joe", Log!A:A >=DATE(2022,11,1), Log!A:A <= DATE(2022,11,5))))

You can automate it a bit more if you put the dates in cells. You could do something like this:
[image]

Then you can make a query for Names and Total Miles in A2:

> =query(Log!$A:$C,"SELECT B,SUM(C) where B is not null and A >=date'"&text(B1,"YYYY-mm-dd")&"' and A <=date'"&text(C1,"YYYY-mm-dd")&"' group by B label SUM(C) 'Total Miles'",true)

And use this byrow formula in C3:
=byrow(A3:A,lambda(each,if(each="","",counta(unique(FILTER(Log!A:A, Log!B:B = each, Log!A:A >=B$1, Log!A:A <= C$1))))))

Then you can just copy these three rows for each "Challenge Week" and only change the dates and the rest will be set up automatically!

Here you have a copy with this implemented ;) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zO5i699COY5omDjux7-V8EIx_64DiItX4OP3PE-uCFo/edit#gid=0